# UITableViewCell swapping (or Auto Layout) in an iOS 9 World (2015)

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, interface-builder

**Foreword:**

I've read many different approaches to this question, but most are old and rely on checking device orientation and making assumptions about the device being used.

I'm interested in a solution or best practice that works in an iOS 9 world, where "orientation" becomes (mostly) irrelevant and any (universal) app can be presented not only in Compact or Regular size classes, but with wildly varying view sizes within those size classes. See: Split View.

**Problem**

I have a UITableViewCell. Auto Layout is enabled, and constraints have been added to all subviews within the cell.

Because a UITableView cell can display radically different widths across presentations (e.g. the same cell on an iPhone 5 in portrait vs landscape, or the cell within a modal form sheet presented on an iPad) I need to change the cell's layout/appearance based on the width of the table view, or at least present a different cell that has a different layout/appearance.

i.e. when the cell has a short width (e.g. portrait iPhone), I need to display one set of content. When the cell has a larger width (e.g. landscape iPhone or within a form on an iPad), more elaborate content needs to be displayed.

**But...**

This does not appear to be a job for Size Classes: the Compact vs Regular division is too broad.

e.g. a tableview presented on an iPhone 5 in portrait will have a Compact horizontal trait.  But when the tableview is presented within a form on an iPad (in portrait or landscape), it will also be horizontally "Compact". Yet the two presentations have very different widths for the tableview.

**Possible Approach**

First, create two versions of the cell in IB: one for short widths, another with a layout for longer widths.

Then, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check for the table view's width. Call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` with the required cell ID, depending on the table view's width.

This requires doubling up on the work required, but would seem to be plausible.

Problem: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called for visible cells until that cell is scrolled off the screen and back on again.

Possible fix: implement `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and in there call `[tableView reloadData];`   This will force `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be called on all visible cells.

Good/bad?

Any suggestions for a sustainable, device-agnostic approach to handle this?